# Excel auto sums

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to multiply a column of values all by one cell, I have multiplied the first cell in the column by using the formula `=6308*$B$2`, and then drag this down the column but it changes all of the cells in the column to the first answer and formula. I have never experienced this before but have done this many times! I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 4):

The way you've written the formula, every cell will have the exact same formula when you copy it. The `$` makes it an absolute reference instead of a relative one. If the formula was `=6308*$B2`, then copying it would change the reference to `$B3`, `$B4`, etc. Here's the [Microsoft page](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21?CorrelationId=6b60411c-9efe-42ce-a719-64e9e4af82b0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) on relative and absolute references.

Answer (score 0):

Try =product(e3,f3:f5) e3 contains the number you want to multiple by the rest, and the range f3:f5 are the subsequent numbers to multiple by.

This gives a result of e3*f3*f4*f5

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the answer to this question.